# Error on JSON parsing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, nsstring, nsarray

I'm having a problem on parsing a JSON.
That is my code.

```
-(void)requstJson1:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    jsonResponse = [request responseString];
    jsonDic = [jsonResponse JSONValue];
    jsonResult = [[jsonDic valueForKey:@"events"] retain];
    type=[[jsonResult valueForKey:@"time"] retain];
    data=[[jsonResult valueForKey:@"data"] retain];
    NSDictionary *dic=[data JSONValue];
    hp=[[dic valueForKey:@"hp"] retain];
}
```

That is my JSON Response

```
{
    "result": "ok",
    "totalcount": 422,
    "events": [
        {
            "id": "52982168e4b00e53abdace66",
            "deviceId": "203",
            "channelId": "",
            "data": "{\"hp\":\"6586129568\",\"camID\":\"camID120\",\"device_id\":38,\"pairedDeviceId\":\"204\"}",
            "longitude": 103.82,
            "latitude": 1.352,
            "type": "event-intercom-visitor-alert",
            "time": "29/11/2013 05:09:54",
            "blobId": "",
            "messageCount": 0,
            "patchEventVideoURL": "",
            "deviceName": "Intercom"
        }
    ]
}
```

I get all the response but i am not getting this "{\"hp\":\"6586129568\",\"camID\":\"camID120\",\"device_id\":38,\"pairedDeviceId\":\"204\"}"
And get error like this -[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c5cb310
2013-11-29 12:37:33.280 Intercom[14720:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c5cb310'
*** First throw call stack:
Thank you

Comment: Are getting an error on reading the values from NSDictionary?

Comment: json result is an array

Comment: Already several duplictes of this question.

Comment: And use `objectForKey:`, not `valueForKey:` to access dictionary values unless you have specific reasons not to do so. - In this case `valueForKey:` hides the real problem, as it "distributes* over arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for that trouble the JSON is not properly formatted the correct example is :

```
{
    "result": "ok",
    "totalcount": 422,
    "events": [
        {
            "id": "52982168e4b00e53abdace66",
            "deviceId": "203",
            "channelId": "",
            "data": {\"hp\":\"6586129568\",\"camID\":\"camID120\",\"device_id\":38,\"pairedDeviceId\":\"204\"},
            "longitude": 103.82,
            "latitude": 1.352,
            "type": "event-intercom-visitor-alert",
            "time": "29/11/2013 05:09:54",
            "blobId": "",
            "messageCount": 0,
            "patchEventVideoURL": "",
            "deviceName": "Intercom"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this ...

```
-(void)requstJson1:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    jsonResponse = [request responseString];

    jsonDic = [jsonResponse JSONValue];

    NSString * jsonResult = [[jsonDic valueForKey:@"events"] retain];

    NSString * type=[[jsonResult valueForKey:@"time"] retain];

    NSArray * array=[[jsonResult valueForKey:@"data"] retain];

    NSDictionary * data = [array objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString * hp = [data objectForKey:@"hp"];

    NSString * camID = [data objectForKey:@"camID120"];

    NSString * device_id = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[data valueForKey:@"device_id"]];

    ...........
}
```

Comment: thank you but its not working. Get warning "Instance method (value for key not found)" in NSSting *hp.

Comment: jsonResult is a NSString so NSString may not respond to 'objectForKey'

Comment: wait i will post the complete answer

Comment: now try this again ... if your getting the problem still then feel free to ask

Comment: I used to updated Ans. But it getting now error like this. [__NSArrayI objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e563eb0
2013-11-29 14:13:59.399 Intercom[15225:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e563eb0'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: It still get error :( [__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c5c8ee0
2013-11-29 15:23:23.061 Intercom[15519:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c5c8ee0'

Comment: man u send me you project to my email - skriyaz7@gmail.com i will figure it out

Answer (score 0):

If you can control the JSON output, you should definitely avoid JSON as string in JSON. You can nest JSON as deep as you want.

The problem is that the string in your data key is not JSON. It's escaped, so it cannot be read.

You should use NSJSONSerialization or any similar JSON parser. NSJSONSerialization is integrated in iOS, so you should try it:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[[response responseString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

You can also use the response data directly, but I don't know ASIHTTP very well.

Comment: NSString may not be response

Comment: I assume that `-responseString` returns NSString. And if you send a `-JSONValue` message to NSString it may not be parsed entirely. Please try my code! It will help you. "Real" parsers are better anyway. Tell me if it did work! (And see if ASIHTTP has a responseData method or similar so that your device doesn't has to convert back and forth)

Comment: Thank you.I try your code.But it getting warning Class method '+JSONObjectWithData:jsonResponse dataUsingEncoding not found(return type default to id).

Comment: You missed the square brackets. The class method is `+ JSONObjectWithData`. Reread my answer carefully. You will see the bracketss. You messed upcsomething horribly ;-)

Comment: You have to put square brackets: `jsonResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8Encoding`. Or please try to get a NSData object off the response. This would be better and safer.